# JPA lazy insert

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, lazy-evaluation

There's many posts about lazy fetching in JPAs like e.g. Hibernate. However, I couldn't find one mentioning lazy insert.

Let's say my DAO has a List attribute with public getter and setter. Instead of `setMyList(List<Type> mylist)` however I would prefer adding the items one by one, resulting in an interface like `addToMyList(Type item)`. Usually this will translate to an INSERT statement on each call which sounds like a huge overhead. What would be the cleanest way to summarize all additions on the DAO before inserting anything?

Comment: The `INSERT` statements will already be queued until you flush to the database.  Do you have in mind to do a single `INSERT` to the database for many application level inserts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to add the items to your list within the same transaction, or multiple different transactions? I don't think it would be possible to delay/defer inserts across many different transactions, unless you have some caching service which flushes to your datastore less frequently.

If same transaction, each call to your add() method will not trigger an insert in realtime; all the inserts will be executed together at the end of your session/transaction (unless triggered earlier by a select from the same table or a manual api call to flush).

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. Hibernate docs state various techniques here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx